# i'm quite new in node.js learning and getting this error a lot can u help me

Tags: javascript, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag7Wk.png)
i'm getting this error

```
node:internal/fs/utils:348
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '-s'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:600:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:468:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kshit\Desktop\projects\wcat\wcat.js:34:27)     
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '-s'
}
```

i don't know what to do

Comment: You need to add more details for example a screenshot of your code and a description of what you're trying to do in the code

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Answer (score 0):

The path that you have entered to read files may be **invalid** you need to use proper fs syntax to read the files

Comment: let content= "";
for(let i=0;i<fileArr.length;i++)
{
    //buffer
    let bufferContent =fs.readFileSync(fileArr[i]);
    content+=bufferContent+"\r\n";//buffer converted into string

}

Comment: thanks, finally I'm able to solve my problem